# *ngIf async pipe issue

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire, angular-ng-if

I'm working on the Authentication of my Angular 11 project with AngularFire.
I don't know why but I can't make `*ngIf` with the async pipe react to the auth state when refreshing the page.

Here is my code:

AuthService:

```js
[...]
export class AuthService {
  public isAuth$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public router: Router) {

    this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
      if (user) {
                                                           // On reflesh
                                                           // when signed in
        console.log('signed in');                          //display signed in
        console.log('isAuth$:', this.isAuth$.getValue());  //display false

        this.isAuth$.next(true);                           

        console.log('isAuth$:', this.isAuth$.getValue()); //display true

      } else {
        console.log('signed out');
        this.isAuth$.next(false); 
      }
    });
  }

// Some Auth functions

}
```

Component .ts

```js
[...]
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}

  public isAuth$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.authService.isAuth$.getValue());

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isAuth$ = this.authService.isAuth$;
  }

}
```

Component html:

```html
<div>
   <a *ngIf="!(isAuth$ | async)">Sign in</a> 
   <a *ngIf="(isAuth$ | async)">Sign out</a>
<div>
```

What is appening is that when i m signed in and refresh. Angular display the Signed Out state until i click on a field or a button...

On refresh from signed in state the console log display:

```
auth.service.ts:19 signed in
auth.service.ts:20 isAuth$: false
auth.service.ts:22 isAuth$: true
```

The value change on refresh so i was assuming the `async` pipe of `*ngIf` should react to those changes and display the good set of button right away. Hopping on your light to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like:

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}

  public isAuth$ = this.authService.isAuth$

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.isAuth$ = this.authService.isAuth$; --> remove this
  }
}
```

When you use `getValue()` on the `BehaviorSubject`, it will only get the value for that change detection cycle. You don't need to (actually shouldn't) reassign `isAuth$` on `ngOnInit`

Also html

```html
<div>
   <a *ngIf="!(isAuth$ | async)">Sign in</a> 
   <a *ngIf="(isAuth$ | async)">Sign out</a> <!-- missing a $ here -->
<div>
```

You can also group the result like:

```html
<div *ngIf="isAuth$ | async as isAuth>
   <a *ngIf="!isAuth">Sign in</a> 
   <a *ngIf="isAuth">Sign out</a>
<div>
```

Comment: I tried, it do not work.When i do it. ngIf do not react at all

Comment: Have you removed it from your ngOnInit? also you have a typo in your template with one of the isAuths, it's missing the $ sign

Comment: Yes i removed it from ngOnInit. I will edit and correct the typo. thx for your time
But the refresh issue is still there...

Answer (score 0):

I find out the issue wasn't the pipe use or anything like that, but angular detection cycle like eko said.

```js
public auth: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
  ngZone.run(() => {
    this.authService.auth$.subscribe((auth: boolean) => {
      this.auth = auth;
    });
  });
}
```

Component

```html
<div>
   <a *ngIf="!isAuth">Sign in</a> 
   <a *ngIf="isAuth">Sign out</a>
<div>
```

Works perfectly fine.